# How do I view my R workspace saved as file?

Tags: r, workspace

I saved my workspace, and accidently closed R before my report was finished.

now I need to view and resume my work, and my R workspace is saved as a file. It won't open in R.

I opened the saved workspace in notepad and it shows a bunch of symbols:

```
"M†]‹—¼öž­ï%„`àþÝõð¯U/[LƒÿvÛ‰šMð›ßÓ&I»’½Ó·N‰Õ´R×§\&›úÚ.¾’³'“p;¤wTÔHÏÞÐNš¾~¡?B]>¬‚¤QÿCçEo|õ|«²iwõõôã&ÂŽîÜòé¹6¤µïÍù¦,ø†d,È™¥ Á•;šz{#Øfºõ’Óß®ß/Êž,8ÏKÎwê‡ã'ÃW°¸Lm'™..............................................................."
```

Please help me recover my lost work.
Appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: The workspace is a binary compressed file that contains all the objects. You can open it using the `load()` function.

Comment: Hey Ian, can you write out the load() command I should be using? Am a noob :)

Comment: load(filename) says: object 'filename' not found

Comment: load()  says: argument "file" is missing, with no default

Comment: You need to provide the path to the file. Like `load(file="C:/Users/Ian/workspace.R")`, but replacing what's in the quotes with the location of the file.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. when I press Enter, nothing happens

Comment: The objects may have been loaded. Try `ls()`.

Comment: Ok so using ls() gives me all the objects from my session, but not exactly showing me the work I did and the codes i wrote.